# About an application that I am trying to put on the Android Market

Tags: android, google-play

I just put my application on the market. It says that "succesfuly published" on the page after everything has done but we can not see it. I wonder that do we have to wait for any confirmation by google? If no what should we do? Can anybody tell me about the publish process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wait for a while (1-2 hours or better) to find it in android market :)

Comment: Do they check the application which we upload onto the market like Apple or whole responsibility belongs to us?

Comment: I don't believe that any human eyes "check" it. But it does sometimes take a while for the servers to get it listed and for it to start showing up.

Answer (score 2):

Usually first version is visible in 10-20 minutes using direct app link, but is not visible via search. When application is updated, the update is usually visible withing several hours.

The direct link has next form:

```
https://market.android.com/details?id=<package-name>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed it show up after varying times. Sometimes it is nearly instant, others it takes an hour or 2.

Make sure that you've not included any manifest filters, or any options from the Market Console site while uploading that would cause it to get filtered out for your specific device.